# Why does repeatmasker annotate transposons of length 1?

Tags: sequence-annotation, repeat-elements, repeat, repeatmasker

I am working on Mac OSX. I have downloaded RepeatMasker from [www.repeatmasker.org](http://www.repeatmasker.org/RepeatMasker-open-4-0-7.tar.gz). I have downloaded RepBase from [www.girinst.org](https://www.girinst.org/). I have download the WS266 version of the *C. elegans* genome from [WormBase](http://www.wormbase.org). I have installed nhmmer using conda.

I have then run the following command:

```
repeatmasker -s -lib RepBase23.08.fasta/celrep.ref -dir annotation/
-gff c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS266.genomic.fa
```

I then imported the annotation table into R. I notice that some transposons have a length of 1!

How is this possible?!

Also, how can repeatmasker calculate such percent divergence, deletion, insertion with a query width of 1? For some of these predictions, both the query and repeat lengths are 1 (so an alignment of 1 nucleotide against 1 nucleotide!)! But the Smith-Waterman scores don't match this. There is something important I am missing here. Can someone help me interpret the table below and explain why some transposons have a length of 1 in the genome?

Thanks.

[image: Transposons of length 1]

The image only contains transposons with a width of 1 as far as I understand. I've selected the rows where queryBegin == queryEnd. The queryBegin variable = queryEnd for all the lines here. It is a subset of the original data frame.